# Decreasing resolution of NetCDF data with GDAL

Tags: gdal, netcdf, gdal-translate

I have wind speed data which is in NetCDF format and lat=4320 lon=8640 and I want to convert it to a NetCDF file with lat=360 and lon=720. In other words, I want to change the resolution of my data whose resolution is 0.0416 degrees (1/24th), and convert it to 0.5 degrees. (By lon and lat, I mean longitude and latitude.) I have already used this code but I have some errors. Could you please help me?

```
gdal_translate -of netCDF -tr 0.5 0.5 WS.nc WS_1.nc
```

```
Warning 1: No UNIDATA NC_GLOBAL:Conventions attribute

Input file size is 8640, 4320

0Warning 1: Recode from UTF-8 to CP_ACP failed with the error: "Invalid 
argument".

...10...20...30...40...50...60...70...80...90..Warning 1: Recode from UTF-8 to CP_ACP failed with the error: "Invalid argument".

.100 - done.
```

Comment: To "increase" resolution, the the pixel density should *increase*  (be made smaller).  Changing pixel size from 0.0416 to 0.5 degrees is a *decrease* in resolution, with pixels 144 times larger in area.

Comment: Do you have any idea how can I fix these errors?

Comment: I can see two warnings but no errors. The output can still be OK, did you check it?

Comment: Yes, I have checked the file and the resolution has changed. You mean that These warnings are not important, and I can ignore them?

Comment: Yes, the two warnings are about missing a global attribute that specifies the sort of data stored in the netcdf file, and a mismatch between ASCII code schemes.   You should be able to ignore those warnings and the numerical data should all be fine.

Comment: Do you know how can I change the resolution of NetCDF data to start at a specific point? when I decrease the resolution from 0.04 to 0.5 the output data starts at the point which has latitude= -89.75 and longitude= -179.75?